# How to bake multiple audio sounds to f curve?

Tags: fcurves

I want to add three different audio clips to same character's mouth using bake sound to f curve. But I am able to add only one sound clip. when i try to add second clip, it replaces the first one. Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

**Bake to custom properties to drive from.**

---

As an example I've made 3 custom properties on the default cube.
Add a keyframe and bake to sound for each.

[image]

*Image. Baked prop, added keyframe to prop2.*

Now let's say we want to drive the cube's x location by these props.

Add a driver to the location.x field. Hover over with mouse, right click, *`add drivers > manually create later single`*.  Put the graph editor in Drivers mode, select the location.x driver, hit <kbd>N</kbd> and choose drivers tab.

[image]

with scripted expression chosen (default) and the "use self" option checked, can type (or paste) in an expression, where `self` is the Cube object, adnd `self["prop"]` is the value of baked property "prop".

The following sums the three.

```
self["prop"] + self["prop1"] + self["prop2]"
```

or another way using `sum`

```
sum([self["prop"], self["prop1"], self["prop2]"])
```

average

```
sum([self["prop"], self["prop1"], self["prop2]"]) / 3
```

the `max`imum.

```
max([self["prop"], self["prop1"], self["prop2]"])
```

Or if you cannot add the properties to what you are animating, can set up the drivers the old fashioned way  with variables.  Add a single property type variable for each, select the Cube as the target object and the datapath is `["prop"]` for "prop"

[image]

The expression uses the variable names, I've used `p0` , `p1`, `p2`.  Similarly to above, the sum would be.

```
sum([p0, p1, p2])
```

or by choosing `'SUM'` as the driver type.