# How to add a minimum value to f-curves

Tags: scale, audio, fcurves

I want to make a plane change the scale to an audio signal. Now when I try using the **bake sound to f-curve**-function it obviously starts with the scale at the value 0. Is there a way to give it a minimum value so that it starts with the normal size I gave it before and only moves above that one and doesn't shrink?

Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bake indirectly to custom property**

If you add a custom property, in this case on the cube, give it a keyframe,  *Note make sure to set the maximum to more than 1 when defining the custom property*

[image]

Bake your sound to custom prop.

[image]

Drive a value with the custom property. Here I'm driving z scale of the cube

[image]

Can type a driver expression straight into property box. Initially a hash `#` signifies it to be a driver.

[image]

In 2.79, switch graph editor to drivers mode.
[image]

Because I used the same object that has the custom property as the one who's scale I wish to drive I can use self in drivers.  *Note since use self is not default, have to set this manually, and will need to update dependencies, since without use self, it doesn't know itself*

The driver expression is

```
1 + self["prop"]
```

returning a minimum of one when the bake is zero.

Can amplify, etc

```
1 + 20 * self["prop"]
```

Or to make things more interesting. add two more custom properties.

```
self["min"] + self["amp"] * self["prop"]
```

allowing the animation of the minimum the amplification.

If you know the maximum of the fcurve can use a generator or an envelope to adjust.

[What's the range of values on a sound-baked f-curve?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/whats-the-range-of-values-on-a-sound-baked-f-curve)

[How can you invert an F-Curve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127895/how-can-you-invert-an-f-curve)

*Please Note, the now-defunct sound drivers addon was my first addon project.  I have it way back on the back burner, and am replacing it with a third party module [`aubio`](https://aubio.org/) version.  Check out the site, baking sound is much quicker with `aubio`*

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot! Is there a way to recreate that in Blender 2.79? I don't find those settings to edit the driver there?

Comment: Not sure where you are getting stuck. Added pick of drivers editor in 2.79 and how to quickly add the driver.