# How to bake multiple sounds to f-curve to the same object

Tags: shape-keys, audio, dopesheet, fcurves, nla-editor

So im animating a characters mouth using shapekeys and baking them to an audio clip. I want to add three different audio clips to the same character's mouth using bake sound to f curve. But, when i try baking the second audio clip, it replaces the previous audio clip.

My question is, how do I add multiple audio clips to same object using bake sound to f-curve. (I don't want to use armatures)

I've heard that you can use the NLA editor in order to then push the action from the action editor or something... I have no idea how that works, can you help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

**Pushing Down (or Stashing) to the [NLA](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/nla/index.html)**

[image]

- Bake your fcurve as you've done.

  - Give the action a meaningful name, I've switched to dope sheet shape key editor mode to do this. Can push down / stash / rename directly from the NLA editor too.
  - Hit the push down button
  - Switch to the [NLA editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/nla/index.html) and move your strip where you wish to play in the timeline.

Consult the docs re the difference between push down and stash, and other info re using the NLA Editor.

- Repeat.  Notice in image above I have already done this once.. with the previous bake "MyAction.001".

**Custom Properties and drivers.**

[How to bake multiple audio sounds to f curve?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93161/how-to-bake-multiple-audio-sounds-to-f-curve)

A suggestion is add a speaker, parent it such that it sticks out the mouth. When a speaker has a sound loaded it is loaded as an audio strip in the NLA. It never has the correct length. Match it to the length of your sound bake for that sound.

[image]

SoundAction is a baked sound on a custom property on a speaker.
NLAStrip (in aqua) is the sound the speaker plays resized to match.

I used this concept for the now defunct sound drivers addon. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/39241/15543

*No armatures have been used in this answer*