# How to bake sound to f-curves without overwriting the previous sound bake?

Tags: baking, audio

Let's say I use bake sound to f-curves function to bake my music file into an objects z location starting on frame 1. Let's say the file ends on frame 3000. So I will move my cursor on frame 3001 and start a new sound bake of a different music file.

This second files bakes itself onto my objects z location with frame 3001 being the start. But it overwrites my previous bake that was in between frames 1 to 3000 and leaves nothing behind.

How do I prevent this function from overwriting previously baked data?

Comment: could bake to a custom property and drive from it.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/93164/15543  Or bake multiple actions  with each sound  baked from frame 1, then  arrange_eg_ move start frame,  using the NLA.

Answer (score 2):

As per @batFINGER answer and his provided link, it's possible to create a custom property, keyframe it and bake the sound into it.

I can therefore create *prop* and bake sound into it starting on frame 1.

Then I can create a *prop1* and bake sound into it starting on frame 3000.

[image]

Finally, I can add a driver onto my objects z location. Such driver should have two variables set to *single property* and its path has to be in a format *["property_name"]*. Variable name can be anything and the drivers expression should sum the two variables by their names.

[image]

Comment: Using `SUM` as driver type removes need for the scripted expression